# Push values into array with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a problem pushing values into an array with mongoose (yes I have read many topics about it and tried many ways to do it).

So I have this schema

```
const Postit = new Schema({
    text: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    status: {
        type: String,
        default: 'TODO'
    },
    modified: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    user: {
        type: ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        required: true
    },
    collaborators: [String]
})
```

And I'm trying to push a string in the collaborators property where the queries match.

So this is the method I use to update it

```
addCollaborator(uid, pid) {
  return Postit.updateOne({
    _id: pid, 
    user: uid 
  }, 
  { $push: { collaborators: 'pepe' } }, 
  (err, raw) => {
    //TO DO
  })
}
```

But nothing happens. The query match because if I change $push for $set and put a new value to status property for example it updates.

The funny thing is that if I run it in mongodb client terminal it works.

```
db.postits.updateOne({
  _id: ObjectId("5beb1492cf484233f8e21ac1"), 
  user: ObjectId("5beb1492cf484233f8e21abf")
}, 
  { $push: {collaborators: 'pepe' }
})
```

What i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Pick `promises` or `callbacks` but do not mix them together. Either you do:

```
addCollaborator(uid, pid) {
  Postit.updateOne({
    _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(pid), 
    user: uid 
  }, 
  { $push: { collaborators: 'pepe' } }, 
  (err, raw) => {
    // TO DO
  })
}
```

Or you do:

```
addCollaborator(uid, pid) {
  return Postit.updateOne({
    _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(pid), 
    user: uid 
  }, 
  { $push: { collaborators: 'pepe' } }).exec()
  .then(result => {
    // TO DO
  })
}
```

Also make sure your objectId is an actual `mongoose.Types.ObjectId`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem is I was using an old schema.

The code works perfectly. Enough code for today...